# Analysis of airport utilization using PANDAS

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to find a vectorized (or more efficient) solution to an iteration problem, where the only solution I found requires row by row iteration of a DataFrame with multiple loops. The actual data file is huge, so my current solution is practically unfeasible. I included line profiler outputs at the very end, if you'd like to have a look.

The main issue seems to be the increased overhead due to frequent Pandas access for filtering operations, especially when creating the temporary DataFrame `dfTemp`. Any ideas on modifying the algorithm and minimizing Pandas usage are welcome. I am also open to Numpy/Cython/Numba implementations.

#### Problem Statement

An airport has two landing strips side by side. Each plane lands (arrival time), taxis on one of the landing strips for a while, then takes off (departure time). Looking for solutions to two cases:

1. Build a list of events where there are more than one plane present on a **single** strip at a time. Do not include subsets of events (e.g. do not show `[3,4]` if there is a valid `[3,4,5]` case). The list should store the indices of the actual DataFrame rows. See function `findSingleEvents()` for a solution for this case (runs around 5 ms).
2. Build a list of events where there is at least one plane on **each** strip at a time. Do not count subsets of an event, only record the event with maximum number of planes. (e.g. do not show `[3,4]` if there is a `[3,4,5]` case). Do not count events that fully occur on a single strip. The list should store the indices of the actual DataFrame rows. See function `findMultiEvents()` for a solution for this case (runs around 15 ms).

#### Code with sample input

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from __future__ import division

data =  [{'PLANE':0, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':85.00, 'DEPARTURE':86.00},
         {'PLANE':1, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':87.87, 'DEPARTURE':92.76},
         {'PLANE':2, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':88.34, 'DEPARTURE':89.72},
         {'PLANE':3, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':88.92, 'DEPARTURE':90.88},
         {'PLANE':4, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':90.03, 'DEPARTURE':92.77},
         {'PLANE':5, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':90.27, 'DEPARTURE':91.95},
         {'PLANE':6, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':92.42, 'DEPARTURE':93.58},
         {'PLANE':7, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':94.42, 'DEPARTURE':95.58}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PLANE','STRIP','ARRIVAL','DEPARTURE'])

def findSingleEvents(df):
    events = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        #Create temporary dataframe for each main iteration
        dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
        if len(dfTemp)>1:
            #convert index values to integers from long
            current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
            #loop backwards to remove elements that do not comply
            for i in reversed(current_event):
                if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
                    current_event.remove(i)
            events.append(current_event)
    #remove duplicate events
    events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    return events

def findMultiEvents(df):
    events = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        #Create temporary dataframe for each main iteration
        dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
        if len(dfTemp)>1:
            #convert index values to integers from long
            current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
            #loop backwards to remove elements that do not comply
            for i in reversed(current_event):
                if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
                    current_event.remove(i)
            #remove elements only on 1 strip
            if len(df.iloc[current_event].STRIP.unique()) > 1:
                events.append(current_event)
    #remove duplicate events
    events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    return events

print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==1])
print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==2])
print findMultiEvents(df)
```

#### Output

```
[[1, 3]]
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

#### Line Profiler Logs

```
%lprun -f findSingleEvents findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==1])

Timer unit: 2.85099e-07 s

Total time: 0.0172055 s
File: <ipython-input-33-220dd9d5b99b>
Function: findSingleEvents at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def findSingleEvents(df):
     2         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      events = []
     3         4       8702.0   2175.5     14.4      for row in df.itertuples():
     4         3      31604.0  10534.7     52.4          dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
     5         3         65.0     21.7      0.1          if len(dfTemp)>1:
     6         6        334.0     55.7      0.6              current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
     7         6         50.0      8.3      0.1              for i in reversed(current_event):
     8         4      19537.0   4884.2     32.4                  if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
     9                                                               current_event.remove(i)
    10         2         12.0      6.0      0.0              events.append(current_event)
    11         1         33.0     33.0      0.1      events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    12         1          3.0      3.0      0.0      return events

%lprun -f findMultiEvents findMultiEvents(df)

Timer unit: 2.85099e-07 s

Total time: 0.0532152 s
File: <ipython-input-28-97265d757453>
Function: findMultiEvents at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def findMultiEvents(df):
     2         1         18.0     18.0      0.0      events = []
     3         9      21661.0   2406.8     11.6      for row in df.itertuples():
     4         8      60694.0   7586.8     32.5          dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
     5         8        145.0     18.1      0.1          if len(dfTemp)>1:
     6        32       1208.0     37.8      0.6              current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
     7        32        152.0      4.8      0.1              for i in reversed(current_event):
     8        26      87007.0   3346.4     46.6                  if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
     9         6         67.0     11.2      0.0                      current_event.remove(i)
    10         6      15636.0   2606.0      8.4              if len(df.iloc[current_event].STRIP.unique()) > 1:
    11         6         38.0      6.3      0.0                  events.append(current_event)
    12         1         27.0     27.0      0.0      events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    13         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      return events
```

Comment: your data seems sort by ARRIVAL, if it's the case, at least you can use a break in the`for i in reversed...` as once you find an ARRIVAL smaller than all DEPARTURE of `dfTemp`, all the one after in this loop will be smaller, so you can add `else: break` after the `if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL ...`. Should save some times

Comment: what do you mean by your data is huge?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a simpler approach here: just keep track of which planes are where, as you go chronologically through time. This way, you only go through the data once, and you don't have to create `dfTemp`.

```
def findEvents(df):

    # An event: a list of indices of the df rows representing planes involved 
    # in the event.

    # Planes present on the strips. 
    strips = {
        1: [],
        2: []
    }

    single_events = {
        1: [],
        2: []
    }
    multi_events = []

    for row in df.sort_values(by=['ARRIVAL']).itertuples():

        # Check for departed planes first
        for planes in strips.values():
             remove_departed_planes(row.ARRIVAL, planes)

        strips[row.STRIP].append(row)

        # Single Event: 
        # Build a list of events where there are more than one plane present on 
        # a single strip at a time. Do not include subsets of events.
        for strip_name in (1, 2):
            if len(strips[strip_name]) > 1:
                indexes = frozenset(int(row.Index) for row in strips[strip_name])
                add_event(single_events[strip_name], indexes)

        # Multi Event
        # Build a list of events where there is at least one plane on each strip 
        # at a time. Do not count subsets of an event. 
        # Do not count events that fully occur on a single strip. (???) 
        if strips[1] and strips[2]:
            indexes = frozenset(int(row.Index) for row in strips[1]) | \
                      frozenset(int(row.Index) for row in strips[2])
            add_event(multi_events, indexes)

    # Sort the sets, for consistent output 
    return (
        {
            1: [sorted(event) for event in single_events[1] ],
            2: [sorted(event) for event in single_events[2] ],
        },
        [sorted(event) for event in multi_events]
    )

def remove_departed_planes(time, planes):
    i = 0
    while i < len(planes):
        if planes[i].DEPARTURE < time:
            del planes[i]
        else:
            i += 1

def add_event(events, event):
    """ Adds an event (list of indexes) to the events list.

        If the event is a subset of the previous or vice versa,
        the biggest set is kept.
    """
    if events and events[-1] < event:
        # Replace
        events[-1] = event
    elif events and events[-1] >= event:
        # Previous event already covers this event
        pass
    else:
        # Neither is a subset of each other
        events.append(event)


print "findSingleEvents and findMultiEvents"
t1 = time.time()
print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==1])
print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==2])
print findMultiEvents(df)
t2 = time.time()
print t2 - t1

print

print "findEvents"
t1 = time.time()
single, multiple = findEvents(df)
print single[1]
print single[2]
print multiple
t2 = time.time()
print t2 - t1
```

Output:

```
findSingleEvents and findMultiEvents
[[1, 3]]
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
0.0490000247955

findEvents
[[1, 3]]
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
0.00300002098083
```

In my opinion, this is also easier to read, test and debug than the more pandas-oriented approach.

You can make this even faster by accessing `row.Index` and `row.Arrival` as `row[0]` and `row[2]`: tuple-like access is faster than dictionary-like access, but less readable.

If I understand you correctly I have "Do not count events that fully occur on a single strip." covered. If not, you will have to adjust the code for this yourself. Good luck!